# Change Delete ActionLink to button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've read that you shouldn't use a link for deletes.  How do I change this to a button instead?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId,applicationId=Model.ApplicationId },  new { @class = "button delete_recipient" })
```

edit
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {

```
        <div id='added_recipients'>

          <table class='header'>
            <tr>
                @if (Model.ListOfRecipients != null)
                {
                <td class='recipient-title'>
                    @if (Model.ListOfRecipients.Count == 1) {@Model.ListOfRecipients.Count.ToString() <span>Recipient</span>}
                    @if (Model.ListOfRecipients.Count > 1)  {@Model.ListOfRecipients.Count.ToString() <span>Recipients</span>}

                </td>
                <td class='express'>
                  Express
                </td>
                <td class='quantity'>
                  Quantity
                </td>
                <td class='action'>
                </td>
                }
            </tr>
          </table>


            @if (Model.ListOfRecipients != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfRecipients.Count; i++)
                { 

                <div class='recipient-wrapper'>
                    <div class='decision_block'>
                        <table class='recipient'>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='recipient-title'>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId)
                                    <h3>
                                    @if(Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientTypeId==1)
                                    {
                                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].MedicalLicensingAuthorityName) 
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].MedicalLicensingAuthorityName)                           
                                     }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientName) 
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientName)
                                    }
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class='delivery-type'>
                                        Delivery Type: @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].DeliveryType)
                                                       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].DeliveryType)
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class='na express'>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].ExpressIndicator)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].ExpressIndicator)
                                </td>
                                <td class='quantity'>
                                    <h3>
                                      Qty @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].Quantity)
                                          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].Quantity)
                                    </h3>
                                </td>
                                <td class='action'>
                                    <input class='button edit_recipient' type='button' value='Edit' />

                                   @* <input class='button delete_recipient' type='button' value='Delete' />*@


                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", 
                                                 "Delete", 
                                                  new { id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId,applicationId=Model.ApplicationId },  
                                                  new { @class = "button delete_recipient",onlick = "$.post(this.href); return false;" }) 


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class='recipient_editable'>
                            <br />
                            <hr />


                            <br />
                            <input class='button update_recipient' type='button' value='Update' />
                            <a class='button cancel_update' href='#'>Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                }
            }


        </div>

        <input class='button' type='submit' value='Continue' />

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anchor tag also to delete using `httppost` verb. you can add `$.post(this.href); return false;` attribute to anchor tag. More can be read [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/simple-jquery-delete-link-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

```
    $(".delete_recipient").click(function() {
     $.post(this.href); 
     return false;
    });

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId,applicationId=Model.ApplicationId },  new { @class = "button delete_recipient" })
```

Comment: where do I add it?  I've tried this  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.ListOfTranscriptRecipients[i].RecipientId,applicationId=Model.ApplicationId },  new { @class = "button delete_recipient",onlick = "$.post(this.href); return false;" })  and it doesn't work

Comment: thanks I got that to work with the [HttpPost]attribut on the controller delete method.

Answer (score 3):

> I've read that you shouldn't use a link for deletes.

That's correct.

> How do I change this to a button instead?

Use a form with a submit button which will `POST` to the `Delete` controller action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId, applicationId = Model.ApplicationId }, FormMethod.Post))
{
   <button type="submit" class="button delete_recipient">Delete</button>
}
```

and to *simulate* a `DELETE` HTTP verb (because DELETE is not supported in standard HTML forms):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", null, new { id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId, applicationId = Model.ApplicationId }, FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
   <button type="submit" class="button delete_recipient">Delete</button>
}
```

and then decorate your Delete controller action with the HttpDelete attribute:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, int applicationId)
{
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have posted your real code it seems that you already have an HTML form outside of the for loop. Since forms cannot be nested this solution won't work. So one possibility is to use AJAX:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    new { 
         id = Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId,
         applicationId = Model.ApplicationId 
    },
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "DELETE",
        OnSuccess = "function() { alert('The item has been deleted'); }"
    },
    new { 
         @class = "button delete_recipient",
    }
)
```

If you don't want to use AJAX you will have to generate those forms outside of the main `Html.BeginForm` to avoid the form nesting.

Comment: I can't use this because the index i is not recognized in the begin form element.

Comment: How is this even possible? If it is recognized inside your `Html.ActionLink` it should be recognized inside your `Html.BeginForm`. They are strictly equivalent in terms of scope. I hope you have wrapped this `Html.BeginForm` inside a `for` loop with the `i` index. Or provide your full code and exact error message if you expect to get helpful answers.

Comment: Now that you have posted your actual code see my updated answer about the nested forms problem.

Comment: that works if don't have the [HttpPost] attribute on the method.  I also tried [HttpDelete] and that didn't work., but it works with no attributes.  thanks